# Problemas em dar commit GITHUB (pasta inacessível no git)

Tags: git, netbeans, commit

Galera, estou com problemas ao tentar *comitar* no github. Como demostra o *print* abaixo, quero *comitar* a pasta *Tecnicas de Programação*, porém não consigo. Já deletei o repositório e o problema continua.

Lembrando comandos como `git add -A`, `git commit -am ""` e `git push origin master` já foram dados e esta pasta esta inacessível para mim (no *git*).

Alguém teria alguma solução? Obrigado.

[image: Problemas com o git]

Comment: Posta o erro por favor

Comment: C:\Users\willi\Documents\NetBeansProjects>git status     modified:   "Tecnicas de Programa\303\247\303\243o" (modified content)    Ele não apresenta erro apenas não  envia a pasta por nada desse  mundo. E não  consigo clicar na pasta no git

Comment: O problema todo é dentro do netbeans? Testou outros clientes de git?

Comment: Sim. Outros repositorios funcionam perfeitamente. Só essa pasta especifica que acontece  isso. Ex:Tenho repositórios sql, eclipse, java etc. Todos  atualizam. Infelizmente essa pasta Técnicas de programação não atualiza.

Comment: O diretório está vazio? O git não versiona diretórios vazios. Este diretório não está referenciado no arquivo .gitignore? Se estiver lá, o git irá ignorar o diretório.

Comment: Não o diretório contem divertas pastas com seus respectivos projetos porém o projeto não é atualizado no git.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e coloque o conteúdo do arquivo .gitignore (se ele existir) na sua pergunta. Acho que não é o caso, mas só para nos certificarmos. Tenta renomear o diretório para outro nome (sem acentos) e veja se consegue versionar assim.

Comment: Então antes estava versionado com acentos e cedilha. Então não pode ser isso. Mas obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Galera resolvi o problema. Mesmo deletando o repositório e  incluindo novamente o problema persistia então resolvi deletar tanto o repositório como a SSH keys e incluir  nova key , inicializei o repositório novamente e realizei commit e dessa vez foi. Ainda não entendi pq do outro jeito não efetuava commit e a pasta estava inacessível, mas tudo bem. Obrigado a todos que tentaram ajudar.